# how to clear all session on byobu

Tags: ubuntu, session, byobu

I want to clear all session at byobu.

Now it asks me which one I want to use:

```
nazar@nazar-desktop:~$ byobu    
Byobu sessions...

  1. tmux: 1: 69 windows (created Tue Feb  4 11:11:00 2014) [80x23]
  2. tmux: 8: 1 windows (created Tue Feb  4 12:28:07 2014) [80x23]
  3. tmux: 9: 1 windows (created Tue Feb  4 12:45:48 2014) [80x23]
  4. Create a new Byobu session (tmux)
  5. Run a shell without Byobu (/bin/bash)
```

I couldn't find any solution.

**How to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
byobu kill-server
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: With `F2` - Create a new window, how to close this new window, if you find it redundant.

Comment: How can I automatically run `byobu` when terminal started? PS this really very cool tool - respect !

Comment: Those are different questions, that should be asked separately here.

Comment: [first one](http://superuser.com/questions/712410/how-to-close-window-at-byobu) and [second](http://superuser.com/questions/712413/how-to-load-byobu-automatically-when-terminal-started).

Comment: maybe also write how to start?