# How to close window at byobu?

Tags: window, byobu

I started to use byobu, and find the it really cool thing.

It has a lot of hot keys. But I couldn't find one of them, and I stuck with one tricky point.

With <kbd>F2</kbd> - you create a new window, but **how to close this window when you don't need it anymore**?

Later I found cool analogy for new window creation - just divide window and - <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>

And you can revert it back - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can either type **exit**, or use Byobu's keybinding for killing windows/panes, which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: This even works when you can't type `exist` because the tab is frozen.

Comment: @KonradHöffner `exit`.

Comment: The question actually asks for closing the whole window at once, not just panel by panel. And either `exit`, `Ctrl+6` or `Ctrl+D` close panel by panel.
Isn't there a way to close all panels from a window at once @dustin-kirkland ?

Comment: I found that the suggested shortcut, `Ctrl-F6`, doesn't work on Mac OS X (maybe because of some system keyboard shortcut). Anyways it works perfectly on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 36):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>k</kbd>

If it asks for confirmation, type `y` and hit enter.

Comment: On Byobu 5.17 (Ubuntu 12.04), with a frozen command prompt, this is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: And this works on the TTY too, where shift commands don't. You saved my day !

Comment: This is correct, and works in CentOS Linux release 7.9

Answer (score 10):

If there are no more jobs running in the window, then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close it.

Comment: What is there are jobs running and you want to kill them all? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> doesn't work for me.

Comment: @lid you can ctrl+c, or from other terminal using `kill`, `pkill` or `killall`.
[Ctrl+D send the EOF character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/209677) (AKA ^D, \04, 0x4), send the signal to end the input stream to tty.

Answer (score 8):

Open a new window pressing F2 (or Fn + F2 on Mac).

From that new window, list all the open windows in current session:

```
byobu list-windows
```

Now, kill the window you want to close (suppose it is window no. 3):

```
byobu kill-window -t 3
```

So, you just have to substitute the last number in the previous instruction by the window's number you want to close.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

Type "exit" at the command prompt.

Comment: I tried this one - this doesn't work. I have read about this at man pages but this didn't work.

Comment: When I use "exit" on my Ubuntu VMs with Byobu, it closes the current window and goes to the previous (assuming I have more than one).  If I only have one, then it closes the entire SSH session.

Comment: at Lubuntu 13.10 this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In my view, if you are using `screen` correct method is to use by pressing

```
Ctrl + a d
```

ie, press `Ctrl + a` then `d`
then type

```
exit
```

So when you type `byobu` you can resume the session. For more details refer.

[How do I get out of a screen without typing 'exit'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847691/how-do-i-get-out-of-a-screen-without-typing-exit)

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct command for closing a window in Byobu if it has many splits in it. However there is a nice workaround. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. This will pull up a prompt for sending the command to all splits of the current window. Now just type `exit` and huzzah!!

This will however not work if one of the splits has something running in it. In that case, manually close such splits by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> several times.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>&</kbd> is better than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>k</kbd> as it will also display the name of the window you are about to kill ==> good as a confirmation.

E.g: 
(hotkeys run from the same split within window "covid19")

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>k</kbd> outputs: Confirm 'kill-window'? (y/n)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>&</kbd> outputs: kill-window covid19? (y/n)