# byobu: How to force close a window?

Tags: byobu

One of the windows within my byobu session mysteriously stops receiving keystrokes. I can open new windows, but that particular window just hangs.

So now, every time I invoked `byobu`, I see 3 windows: 2 that I'm actually using, plus that 1 window that just sits there.

Is there a way to kill that wayward window? Preferably, just that one window. But if I need to clear the whole session, is also alright.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close window at byobu?](https://superuser.com/questions/712410/how-to-close-window-at-byobu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resorted to [this helpful answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459389/149900), i.e.:

```
screen -ls | grep "Detached" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -i screen -X -S {} quit
```

(Of course, I did it manually, `screen -ls` followed by `screen -X -S $screen_session quit`)

Comment: In your question you say Byobu in general, what if using Tmux instead of Screen?

Answer (score 31):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> kills the currently focused window after a `y/n` confirmation in screen/byobu.

Comment: this is what actually worked for me (using putty)

Comment: If you see a prompt, 1 for screen mode, 2 for emacs mode, pick 1, then run this.

Comment: If you are using byobu in Emacs mode, meaning that Ctrl-a is mapped to "start of the line" you can use F12+k instead. F12 always works as the tmux/screen escape

Comment: Thanks, I using an SSH connection into a remote AWS ubuntu box, and this worked for me. Using the command the other commands detached the session without closing the window.

Comment: @JosephMCasey for ssh you could [close ssh connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13998/209677).

Answer (score 23):

You can use [Byobu's](http://byobu.co) hotkey, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> to force-kill windows or panes.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: I tried that, but what happened was PuTTY closing the session. When I reopen a session, entering byobu still shows the 'hung' window?

Comment: Okay, I've reconfigured PuTTY to ignore keyboard shortcuts. `Ctrl+F6` still does not force-kill a window; it just detaches the session.

Comment: On a Mac, this just closes the entire byobu session. Going back in, I still have all the same windows.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using byobu in Emacs mode, meaning that Ctrl-a is mapped to "start of the line" you can use F12+k instead. F12 always works as the tmux/screen escape.

You will be prompted with a yes/no option from there.