# how to load byobu automatically when terminal started?

Tags: terminal, byobu

I'm using Lubuntu 13.10, and I want to load `byobu` automatically when I open terminal.

I found byobu very flexible and reliable tool and want to use every time when I have to use terminal.

I couldn't find this solution or something similar to this at man pages...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you want is to launch the [Byobu](http://byobu.co) desktop application.  You can find that in the Ubuntu application launcher, by simply typing **Byobu**.  You can lock it to the launcher, and the icon will always stay there, on the left.

Alternatively, most Linux terminals can be set to run a particular command or application at launch.

For instance, in Gnome Terminal, simply click **Edit** -> **Profile Preferences**, select the **Title and Command** tab, check the **Run a custom command instead of my shell** box, and enter **/usr/bin/byobu**.

[image: Gnome Terminal preferences]

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 13.10 - with `LXTerminal`. It doesn't have this configuration. Does exist some way to achieve this goal on Lubuntu?

Comment: sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal

Comment: It works fine, however is there a way to not have the log message printed every time a terminal is opened ?

Comment: Dear Dustin, Is there a way to start the terminal WITHOUT the welcome-message with the annoying "Press <enter> to continue..." message?

Comment: I don't know what enter to continue message you're talking about.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `byobu-enable` command. See the related [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/byobu-enable.1.html). To reverse the change, use `byobu-disable`.

`byobu-enable` places a line at the end of ~/.profile. This means it only takes effect for login shells, i.e. via SSH or the VTs. If you're using LXTerminal, it may work if you move that line to ~/.bashrc instead.

Comment: I tried this - but after reopening terminal, I need to type `byobu` for it starting again

Comment: Revised my answer with more details.

Comment: It really uses - LXTerminal. It places - `_byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch` at the end of `.profile`. What exactly should enter to turn it?

Comment: You could configure your gnome-terminal to run as a login-shell, and then this solution will work.

Comment: I had to add the `_byobu_sourced=1...` line to to my `~/.bashrc`